# Multiple Group By and Count

Tags: sql

I was wondering if someone could help me with this. Here is a sample set of my data:

```
FirstName   LastName   Department  Ticket  Hours Shift   DateWorked   Key
Bob         Smith      Sleeves     23235    4     1     2017-01-01    001
Bob         Smith      Sleeves     12345    4     1     2017-01-01    001    
Jim         Bo         Sleeves     12345    8     1     2017-01-01    002
Janet       Moore      Lids        78945    8     2     2017-01-01    003
Jon         Bob        Lids        45621    1.5   3     2017-01-01    004
Jon         Bob        Lids        45621    7.5   3     2017-01-01    004

Bob         Smith      Mugs        12345    8     1      2017-01-02
Jim         Bo         Lids        99999    8     3      2017-01-02
```

It should return something like this:

```
DateWorked   Shift    Department  HeadCount
2017-01-01   1        Sleeves     2  (Bob Smith has two entries but counted as one and Jim Bo makes for 2)
2017-01-01   2        Lids        1  (Janet)
2017-01-01   3        Lids        1  (Jon)
```

Please note that *all departments work all shifts*. This is just a sample set. There can be anywhere from none to a hundred per department.

Also *one employee could work multiple departments in one day*!  I don't know how to account for that.

This is what I have.  So for this example it's not summing Bob Smith. It's counting him as two.

```
SELECT Scheduled, Department, [Shift], COUNT(*) as HeadCount
FROM EmployeeTickets
WHERE  Scheduled >= '2017-01-01' AND Scheduled < '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY Scheduled, Department, [Shift]
ORDER BY Scheduled, Department, [Shift]
```

Thank you.

ETA I don't know if it helps but in the table there is a key per entry, so Bob Smith on Jan 1 would have a key for that day. His social security number is also in there.  I'm trying to group by one of those somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just  use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT Scheduled, Department, [Shift], COUNT( DISTINCT FirstName ) as HeadCount
FROM EmployeeTickets
WHERE  Scheduled >= '2017-01-01' AND Scheduled < '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY Scheduled, Department, [Shift]
ORDER BY Scheduled, Department, [Shift]
```

Of course this will have problem if you have multiple persons with same name. So I hope you have some EmployeeID on your tables, so you can differentiate every employee.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeID)
```

Comment: @Blorgbeard I dont think I can include `LastName` in the the `COUNT` unless I concatenate the strings, but OP didnt specify rdbms. Also that doesnt solve the problem if two person have the same name and last name.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post. I think it might work with their social security number. It happens to be in the table.

Comment: "SSMS" in the question implies SQL Server. Better to use an ID though, you're right.